# EF Core 6- .NET6 - Value of entity obtained from relations stay null

Tags: c#, database, symfony, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

i'm trying to get relations working in EF Core 6, i'm using .NET 6 as i need certain of it's features for my project. i'm using Symfony PHP as my frontend since it made my life easier dealing with entities and my database.

I have An entity called user, which store various data such as an id (it's primary key), an Email address, roles, passwords, plays (i'll explain what it is just after) & username.

```cs
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Email {get; set;}

    public string[] _roles;
    public string Roles
    {
        get => JsonSerializer.Serialize(_roles); 
        set
        {
            _roles = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(value);
        }
    }

    public string Password {get; set;}

    public List<Player> plays {get; set;}

    public string Username {get; set;}

    public string[] GetRoles()
    {
        return _roles;
    }
}
```

I also have an Entity called Player in my database that contain an id (it's primary key), a User (that the player will be associated with) & a Grid (which is just an array of array of Cells (in json format))

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace WebSocket.Entity
{
    [Table("Player")]
    public class Player
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}

        [Column("user_id")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User {get; set;}

        public string Grid 
        {
            get => JsonSerializer.Serialize(_grid); 
            set
            {
                _grid = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<Cell>>>(value);
            }
        }
        private List<List<Cell>> _grid;

        public List<List<Cell>> GetGrid()
        {
            return _grid;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the table structure for both Entites (generated by doctrine):

User:
[User Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIHZA.png)

Player:
[Player Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shz38.png)

as for my context, here it is:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebSocket.Entity;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Linq;

namespace WebSocket.Components.Context
{
    public class EntityContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }

        private Settings Settings { get; }

        public EntityContext()
        {
            var content = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "settings.json"));
            this.Settings = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Settings>(content);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
            => options.UseMySQL($"server={Settings.Host};user={Settings.Username};database={Settings.Db_name};password={Settings.Password};port={Settings.Port}");
    }
}
```

and here is my basic Program.cs as of now:

```cs
class Program
{
    static private EntityContext db;
        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        db = new EntityContext();
        db.Database.GetDbConnection().Open();

        foreach(User user in db.Users)
        {
            if (user.plays == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something wrong happened");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Successfully loaded plays for user {user.Username}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If i run this piece of code, `user.plays` will always be null no matter what solution below i used.

Here are some of the link i've visited and taken every single elements from and tried them one by one, tweaking one thing at a time and hoping it would work every single times as it did for so many peoples:

https://pastebin.com/LcxBiV4n (too many)

I've tried the solution or something similar since some of those use an older version of EF Core, this include:

- virtual
- [ForeignKey("user_id")]
- [ForeignKey("UserId")]
- Mappings
- includes
- probably something else i forgot about already

I have been trying for 6 good hours now and managed to get it working once but then it stopped working and never did again.

EDIT: here, i've tried yet another kind of mapping, and it fail in the most confusing way:

[user_id1 ???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voF6L.png)

Here is the mapping in question

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
        .HasOne<User>(p => p.User)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("user_id");
}
```

EDIT 2: Added solution from Ivan Stoev which i have seen somewhere else where it worked (still not for me)

```
class Program
{
    static private EntityContext db;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        db = new EntityContext();
        db.Database.GetDbConnection().Open();

        // hypothetically working for other peoples?
        db.Users.Include(u => u.plays).ToList();

        foreach(User user in db.Users)
        {
            if (user.plays == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something wrong happened");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Successfully loaded plays for user {user.Username}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

mapping:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
        .HasOne<User>(p => p.User)
        .WithMany(u => u.plays)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);
}
```

Comment: `Include` is what you need in EF Core. EF Core does not load navigation properties  automatically. `virtual` is not necessary, and when present, does not magically lazy load as in EF6 - EF Core requires additional (and again explicit) configuration. Also opening db connection is not necessary and not recommended. Simply do `...in db.Users.Include(e => e.plays))`. For more info, see [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) topic.

Comment: this is one of many solutions i tried, and it unfortunately failed, this is why it's already part of the list, yes, it's `includes` which may seen too general an vague but i couldn't bring myself to write every kind of includes i have seen.

Comment: And use correct fluent mapping. `.HasOne(p => p.User).WithMany(u => u.plays)`.  `WitMany()` w/o argument means something else.

Comment: I don't mean to be harsh, but then you likely screwed up the "includes" attempt. 
This is the correct an proper way to do it. 
Please include an example of what you tried, and any error messages included in said attempt.

Comment: i just want to make sure that i'm not screwing up anything, no mappings, just this include, @IvanStoev https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3utQ.png.  EDIT: the result is the same with the mapping you provided (and fixed a typo in)

Comment: `.HasForeignKey("user_id")` is also wrong. Should be `.HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId)`

Comment: done, still the same result unfortunately, lemme add it to the thread though

Comment: @Galac There is nothing more we can do to help. This is pretty standard relationship, I have done thousands like that, and it works. Again, make sure correct mapping (attributes and fluent) + `Include`. If it doesn't work, then there is something in your real case not shown here.

Comment: I'll re-create a new console project and try again from scratch to see if something got borked or if Omnisharp messed up again, will let you know if it work or not  here prob

Comment: It turns out my suspicions were right, this solution worked, as well as one i had found nearly 6 hours ago now that doesn't require Includes, will keep it that way anyone as it seem like a more reliable solution.